# How do I set auto check to override exploit in metasploit?

Tags: metasploit

I was trying to run the bolt CMS exploit.
`Bolt CMS 3.7.0 - Authenticated Remote Code Execution | php/webapps/48296.py` (taken from searchsploit) and it wouldn't work because automatic check which happens before the exploit is actually ran returned a false result.
I've tried a lot of combinations like set auto check to false and no auto check to see if I can override it but nothing seems to work.
I got it to work once with a different case but I don't remember how.

[image: exploit]

Comment: Have you tried editing the code of the module?

Comment: no i just looked at it

Answer (score 2):

```
Set AutoCheck false
```

AutoCheck is activated by default for a reason. 99% of the time it works correctly. It means that the exploit will NOT work, because the target seems not exploitable.

Comment: Perhaps mention how you can enable `ForceExploit` in order to force the module to ignore this specific check, instead of disabling all checks.

Answer (score 0):

i found out you can `set auto-check false`